# Associating custom submenu item with post type of top level menu item

Tags: admin, wp-admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I'm working on a plugin that sets admin menu submenu pages on all different post types.

I need to be able to associate these new submenu pages with the corresponding post type of the top level menu item. Is this possible without having to rely on using `$_GET`?

I see that `$typenow` is used on `edit.php`, but I cannot use that on my custom page, as it only returns `NULL`.

So basically: How do I set appropriate/associate post type to a custom menu item.

**UPDATED:**

Here's an image that hopefully describes a little bit better what I'm after.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/4q4Dy.jpg]

As it is now, the Custom Item in the submenu is only available when Pages is active since otherwise `$_GET` can't fetch `post_type`.

I'm using:

```
$post_type = esc_attr( $_GET['post_type'] );
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type );    
$title = $post_type_object->labels->name;

$page = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type, $title, $title, 'edit_pages', 'order-' . $post_type, 'cmspo_menu_order_page' );
```

So I need a way to grab the appropriate post type that the custom item should be associated with, in this case it's "page", but there will be custom items under each custom post type that's been registered with the `capability_type` "page" rather than "post".

Comment: Something like this -> http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59417/primary-and-secondary-menus/59447#59447 ?

Comment: @JoshuaAbenazer No, I don't think so, but please elaborate if possible. I've updated my question to be (hopefully) more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the information about the current post type in your callback function that renders the submenu page output. And at this point there is a lot of information ready:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_60730_demo_submenu' );

/**
 * Register sub menu pages.
 *
 * Note that get_current_screen() is still NULL now.
 *
 * @wp-hook admin_menu
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_60730_demo_submenu()
{
    // get public post types
    $post_types = get_post_types( array ( 'public' => TRUE ) );

    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type )
    {
        add_submenu_page(
            "edit.php?post_type=$post_type",
            "Extra $post_type", // this should be made translatable
            "Extra $post_type", // this too
            "edit_{$post_type}s",
            "order-$post_type",
            'wpse_60730_demo_callback'
        );
    }
}
/**
 * Render the sub menu page output.
 *
 * All information is set now.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wpse_60730_demo_callback()
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    global $typenow, $parent_file;
    print "<pre>get_current_screen()\n" . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $screen, TRUE ) ) . '</pre><hr>';
    print "<pre>\$typenow: " . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $typenow, TRUE ) ) . '</pre><hr>';
    print "<pre>\$parent_file: " . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $parent_file, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Solved the problem I was having, changed from edit_{$post_type}s to edit_pages and it all worked out.